# Why are windows/dialogs not part of the class PyQt creates?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm fairly new to Qt. I've built a few things in Gtk3 with introspection and the Glade UI designer.

Now, I'm trying to learn PyQt. While I like how it makes your Ui into a class (seems easier to manage to me), something is puzzling me. When I run `pyuic4` with the `-x` (create executable file) flag, it has this bit of code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_multippp(object):
    def setupUi(self, multippp):
        multippp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("multippp"))
        multippp.resize(371, 43)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(multippp)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(multippp)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)

        self.retranslateUi(multippp)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(multippp)

    def retranslateUi(self, multippp):
        multippp.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("multippp", "Multiple PPP Accounts", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("multippp", "More than one PPP account found, please select one:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    multippp = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_multippp()
    ui.setupUi(multippp)
    multippp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I'm trying to understand in this (generated) code is why the multippp dialog is not part of the class with all the other widgets. Instead, as best I can tell, you hand it a QDialog, and it sculpts it to what you want it to be. Is there an advantage to having the QDialog separate, and if so, what is that advantage?

Comment: I think it's just trying to mimic the C++ interface.

Comment: @icktoofay Is there a reason the C++ interface does it that way? (I know some C++ but not a ton, so maybe I'm missing something obvious?)

Comment: Well, usually you'll have the code that you wrote and the automatically-generated UI code. Obviously, Qt wouldn't want to edit your code to splice in its widget references, so they just generated another class. I guess they still wanted *your* code to be the code that extended the widget, though, so you could override methods of the widget or something. Those constraints kind of force it to be a separate class holding all the references to the widgets, but it itself cannot be the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Sub widgets need a widget container like QMainWindow or QDialog. However, you can also use a widget as Top Level Widget. QDialog is there because pyuic4 doesn't know how you plan to use this designed widget.

In your program QDialog can be any other widget container. Also you can subclass multippp.

**To finalize, the QDialog just a parent to execute your code.**